# Solaris 10 ZFS boot: how to add mirror of boot drive

Tags: zfs

I have a working Solaris 10 box whose boot / disk is using ZFS.

I'd like to add another hard drive and mirror this boot drive.

When I run the command I believe is correct (below) I get an error:

```
-bash-3.2# zpool add -f rpool mirror c1t0d0 c1t1d0
invalid vdev specification
the following errors must be manually repaired:
/dev/dsk/c1t0d0s0 is part of active ZFS pool rpool. Please see zpool(1M).
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Many thanks, Doug

Comment: I don't suppose you actually did what it said and read `man zpool`?

Answer (score 7):

First, you need to make sure the new disk size is equal or larger than the original one.

Duplicate the disk partition (x86 only):

```
fdisk -W /var/tmp/rpool-fdisk /dev/rdsk/c1t0d0p0
fdisk -F /var/tmp/rpool-fdisk /dev/rdsk/c1t1d0p0
```

Duplicate the label (both x86 and SPARC)

```
prtvtoc /dev/rdsk/c1t0d0s0 | fmthard -s - /dev/rdsk/c1t1d0s0
```

Mirror the root pool (both x86 and SPARC):

```
zpool attach -f rpool c1t1d0s0
```

Install the GRUB boot loader (x86 only):

```
installgrub /boot/grub/stage1 /boot/grub/stage2 /dev/rdsk/c1t1d0s0
```

Install the boot loader (SPARC only):

```
installboot -F zfs /usr/platform/`uname -i`/lib/fs/zfs/bootblk /dev/rdsk/c1t1d0s0
```

Set the BIOS (x86) or the OpenBOOT prom (SPARC) to have the new disk bootable.

In the latter case (SPARC), that should be something like:

```
eeprom "boot-device=disk1 disk2"
```

Make sure the ZFS resilvering is completed before rebooting. Use the `zpool status rpool` command to monitor resilvering.

Comment: This is starting to look like a rabbit hole... but: 1) how does one duplicate the disk partitioning/label information on the target disk, and 2) how does one install the boot loader on the second disk?

Comment: Are you using x86 or SPARC hardware ?

Comment: x86 is what I have!

Comment: ok, reply updated with both x86 and SPARC instructions.